# How do we mock our services to test the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing

I'm new to angular js and trying to test a controller.

I have service like this:

```
angular.module('test'){

        service.getAllServices = function()
        {
            var fullPath = url
            var deferred = $q.defer()

            if(!$.isEmptyObject(service.allServices))
                deferred.resolve(service.allServices)
            else
                $http.get(fullPath)
                    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                        service.allServices = data
                        deferred.resolve(service.allServices)
                    })
                    .error(deferred.object)

            return deferred.promise;
        }


    })
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('test')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$http,HttpService) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
        "Loading"
    ];


    $scope.loadServices = function()
    {
        HttpService.getAllServices().then(function(result){
//            console.log("Success")
            $scope.awesomeThings = result.entities
        },function(reason){
            console.log(reason)
        })
    };
```

And I have a test case like this:

```
describe('Testing controller', function () {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('test'));

    var MainCtrl,
        scope;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope,$q,HttpService) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var response = {
            things: 'and stuff'
        }

        deferred.resolve(response);
        spyOn(HttpService, 'getAllServices').andReturn(deferred.promise);

        MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            HttpService : HttpService
        });

        scope.loadServices();
    }));


    it('Controller is dummy, just gives back, what services gives back', function () {
        expect(scope.awesomeThings).toEqual({
            things: 'and stuff'
        });
    });


});
```

Even though I'm injecting the `deferred` object, looks like still my test case is failing, with this message:

```
Expected [ 'Loading' ] to equal { things : 'and stuff' }.
```

Where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call digest to force the promise success function to run. You can do it in your test, or in your set up after the call to loadServices like so:

```
scope.loadServices();
scope.$digest();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Couple of thing: 1. what is result.entities? Surely you just want $scope.awesomeThings = result. 2. In debugger, is the code $scope.awesomeThings = result.entities being run?

Comment: Oh bad. It works! Thanks. Can you explain me why that `$digest();` is required?

Comment: When promises are resolved, the success/error functions get ran during the AngularJS digest cycle. You don't usually call digest() in your production code, but when you're testing an asynchronous action you'll need to call it. Have a look here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle for more info.